# Allow only single aplication to access files on USB stick with Linux namespaces

Tags: linux, usb-drive, isolation

It looks like i found a way to allow only single application to access files in USB storage. 
This script must be run with sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash
# create namespace
unshare -m<<EOF
# mount device in namespace
mount -U "UUID-here" "/home/$SUDO_USER/hidden"
# run unprivileged application 
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" application
# unmount device
umount "/home/$SUDO_USER/hidden"
EOF
```

Obviously automounter must not mount this device.

Is it possible for other applications (except 0day exploits) run by user to read files from namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, other processes owned by the same user can access the files via `/proc/`<PID>`/root`.

This can be prevented by root creating a user namespace, mapping the unprivileged user, then switching to the user. These steps need to preformed by a single executable.

Comment: I cant reproduce it on my script (root owns /proc/keepass_PID/root and im getting 'Permission denied'), running with sudo its a reason right?